# Ghost blog popup halfway through article

Tags: ghost-blog

I have a ghost blog and would like to popup a div element with content inside when the user scrolls halfway through each article.

How would i go about this? I can paste code into the code injection area where it says:

```
Site Header

Code here will be injected into the {{ghost_head}} tag on every page of the site
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `ghost_foot` inside the `code injection` option if you want to inject the code into the body of the ghost blog.

If you want to add your code between `<head>...</head>` then use `ghost_head` inside the `code injection`.